# cross domain request returning Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to get the JSON object that is created in a remote server and pull it on the page. I have tried every combination with "data type", "type", callback etc but keep getting same "unexpected token :" error.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
$(function(){
    var url = "http://someurl.com/api/count?url=http://www.yyets.com";
    $.jsonp({
        url: url,
        corsSupport: true, // if URL above supports CORS (optional)
        jsonpSupport: true, // if URL above supports JSONP (optional)
        jsonp:'jsonp',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data, status){
            alert("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(data){
          alert('Completed.');
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
            alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

On the console the unexpected token error points to the url:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :             http://someurl.com/api/count?url=http://www.yyets.com&_xx1358645456540=1

I also did some error handling with:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             if (window.console) console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);

       }
```

This time it throws,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : count:1
>   Error... parsererror        Error: jQuery19005587419604416937_1358646210172 was not called

Can you please help!!

Comment: there are a number of posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: I have tried every recommendation in those tickets. But still no luck. I am really desperate

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The page which called by javascript have to have that header

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: It has header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); on the requested page