# Eval() = Unexpected token : error

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I tried this simple JavaScript code:

```
eval('{"Topics":["toto","tata","titi"]}')
```

In the Chrome console, for example, this returns

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I tried the JSON on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it's valid.

Do you see the bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FWIW, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead. Safer than `eval`.

Answer (score 52):

You have to write like this

```
eval('('+stringJson+')' );
```

to convert an string to Object

Hope I help!

Comment: This was the only solution that worked in my case. Thank you!

Comment: thx, this is much better than accepted answer. It is good to point out that eval is evil :), but still, this answers the question.

Comment: I had the same issue evaluating a normal javascript function and this solved my problem. Why / how does wrapping an expression in parenthesis fix the problem?

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 31):

Because `eval` *does not* force an expression context and the string provided is an *invalid* JavaScript program, thus the first three tokens (and how they are looked at) are:

```
{            // <-- beginning of a block, and NOT an Object literal
"Topics"     // <-- string value, okay (note this is NOT a label)
:            // <-- huh? expecting ";" or "}" or an operator, etc.
```

Happy coding.

Comment: may I ask you why eval('function(){}') throws an exception too ?

Comment: @BiAiB For the same reason as above :) The contents of `eval` run in a *statement* context and thus it is taken as a FunctionDeclaration grammar construct. The error generated by that is "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name". Either give it a name (`eval('function f(){}'); f()`) or force it into a FunctionExpression construct (`f = eval('(function(){alert("hi")})'); f()`). See http://es5.github.com/x13.html

Comment: thanks! the tricky part to me was because strings like '3' are correctly evaluated, and not 'function(){}'. The second cannot be evaluated as an ExpressionStatement: `an ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration` (http://es5.github.com/x12.html#x12.4)

Answer (score 9):

Number one: Do not use eval.

Number two. Only use eval to make something, well be evaluated. Like for example:

```
eval('var topics = {"Topics":["toto","tata","titi"]}');
```

Answer (score 4):

Because that's evaluating an object. eval() requires you to pass in syntactically valid javascript, and all you're doing is passing in a bare object. The call should be more like:

```
eval('var x = {"Topics":etc...}');
```

Answer (score 4):

USE:

```
function evalJson(jsArray){ eval("function x(){ return "+ jsArray +"; }"); return x(); }

var yourJson =evalJson('{"Topics":["toto","tata","titi"]}');

console.log(yourJson.Topics[1]); // print 'tata''
```

Comment: works for me..don't know if it is the best practice, but it got me up and running

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JQuery use the function `$.parseJSON()`, worked for me, had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make an array use the below code

```
var jsonObject = eval('(' +"["+ response + "]"+')');
```