# Angular Dynamic Component Based on HTTP call

Tags: angular

Create Component template and Typescript code dynamically.

I am trying to generate the component on the fly, HTTP service call send us HTML template and Typescript code. In this we are able to set HTMl template dynamically but not typescript code, not able to figure out how to set typescript code dynamically.

*** Please find below code which renders HTML template based on HTTP call. ***

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Compiler, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _compiler: Compiler, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    return this.http.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ketan-gote/stackblitz-demo/master/template.txt", { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((txt: any) => {
      console.log(txt);
      const tmpCmp = Component({ template: txt, selector: 'abcd' })(class {

      });
      const tmpModule = NgModule({ imports: [HttpClientModule], declarations: [tmpCmp], entryComponents: [tmpCmp] })(class {
      });

      this._compiler.compileModuleAsync(tmpModule)
        .then((moduleFactory) => {
          debugger;
          const resolver = moduleFactory.create(this._injector).componentFactoryResolver;
          const f = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(tmpCmp);
          const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
          this._container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
        })
    });

  }
}
```

Here's [a working link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-http?file=src/app/app.component.ts) !

*** PROBLEM**  
Now when we are trying to get TS code also as part of response it gives error  **core.js:12501 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__annotations__' of undefined ***

Please find below code which renders TS

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Compiler, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _compiler: Compiler, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    return this.http.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ketan-gote/stackblitz-demo/master/ts.txt", { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((txt: any) => {
      console.log(txt);
      const tmpCmp = Component({ template: "<h1>HEAD</h1>", selector: 'abcd' })(txt);
      const tmpModule = NgModule({ imports: [HttpClientModule], declarations: [tmpCmp], entryComponents: [tmpCmp] })(class {
      });

      this._compiler.compileModuleAsync(tmpModule)
        .then((moduleFactory) => {
          debugger;
          const resolver = moduleFactory.create(this._injector).componentFactoryResolver;
          const f = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(tmpCmp);
          const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
          this._container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
        })
    });

  }
}
```

Here's  [is not working code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-ts-http)!

Answer (score 0):

i know it's late, but this can be done with 'eval' function.

Change the line from this

```
const tmpCmp = Component({ template: "<h1>HEAD</h1>", selector: 'abcd' })(txt);
```

to this

```
const tmpCmp = Component({ template: "<h1>HEAD</h1>", selector: 'abcd' })(eval('(' +txt+ ')'));
```

I found the answer in this post ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377840 ).