# Displaying a polygon with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polygon, gmaps4rails

Ruby noob here.  Trying to display a list of points as a polygon on a google map using the gmaps4rails gem (awesome gem by the way).  Any suggestions based on code sample below would be much appreciated! I can see the outline for the map, but no map and no polygon.  Update:  this code has been updated and the problem is solved.

Class Schoolpoint is a list of lat/long pairs that belong to School

In my controller:

```
@polyjson = []
schoolpoints = []    
Schoolpoint.where(:school_id => params[:id]).each do |point|
  schoolpoints << { :lng => point.longitude, :lat => point.latitude}
end
@polyjson = [schoolpoints]
@polyjson = @polyjson.to_json
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= gmaps({"polygons" => { "data" => @polyjson }})
```

in Schoolpoint model:

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :place

  acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{longitude}, #{latitude}" 
  end
end
```

Update:  This error now longer exists, but I've left it in case its helpful to someone dealing with similar problem.  Finally, here is the resulting js with an uncaught Syntaxerror => unexpected token.

```
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.polygons = [[{"lng"=>-80.190262, "lat"=>25.774252, "strokeColor"=>"#FF0000", "strokeOpacity"=>0.3, "strokeWeight"=>1, "fillColor"=>"#FF0000", "fillOpacity"=>0.7}, {"lng"=>-87.6245284080505, "lat"=>41.8868315803506}, {"lng"=>-87.6241636276245, "lat"=>41.8674515900783}, {"lng"=>-87.6203870773315, "lat"=>41.8674835487326}, {"lng"=>-87.6167392730712, "lat"=>41.8579591627635}, {"lng"=>-87.6348495483398, "lat"=>41.8577034549953}, {"lng"=>-87.6342701911926, "lat"=>41.8588701133785}, {"lng"=>-87.6341199874878, "lat"=>41.858946025344}, {"lng"=>-87.6341146230697, "lat"=>41.8590858629394}, {"lng"=>-87.6341199874878, "lat"=>41.8600767034266}, {"lng"=>-87.6342219114303, "lat"=>41.8612433185139}, {"lng"=>-87.634157538414, "lat"=>41.8613112372298}, {"lng"=>-87.6342540979385, "lat"=>41.8621502271823}, {"lng"=>-87.6341950893402, "lat"=>41.8622580965204}, {"lng"=>-87.6342433691024, "lat"=>41.8626336402037}, {"lng"=>-87.6341092586517, "lat"=>41.8630930789441}, {"lng"=>-87.6342326402664, "lat"=>41.8631010691539}, {"lng"=>-87.6342862844467, "lat"=>41.8651984646832}, {"lng"=>-87.6342165470123, "lat"=>41.865314318812}, {"lng"=>-87.6342540979385, "lat"=>41.865929540668}, {"lng"=>-87.6343238353729, "lat"=>41.8661652409794}, {"lng"=>-87.6343667507171, "lat"=>41.8664728485533}, {"lng"=>-87.6342701911926, "lat"=>41.866564731048}, {"lng"=>-87.6343882083892, "lat"=>41.8673317449823}, {"lng"=>-87.6344525814056, "lat"=>41.8680388278011}, {"lng"=>-87.6346457004547, "lat"=>41.8691693450993}, {"lng"=>-87.6346671581268, "lat"=>41.8696886572982}, {"lng"=>-87.6345813274383, "lat"=>41.8698804022745}, {"lng"=>-87.6347583532333, "lat"=>41.869992253245}, {"lng"=>-87.634892463684, "lat"=>41.8706873227465}, {"lng"=>-87.6353269815445, "lat"=>41.8726167002032}, {"lng"=>-87.6352626085281, "lat"=>41.8728443868687}, {"lng"=>-87.6354557275772, "lat"=>41.8730081609862}, {"lng"=>-87.6353698968887, "lat"=>41.8732797854267}, {"lng"=>-87.6356971263885, "lat"=>41.8740227522642}, {"lng"=>-87.6356971263885, "lat"=>41.8746458790817}, {"lng"=>-87.6359224319458, "lat"=>41.87509724279}, {"lng"=>-87.6361316442489, "lat"=>41.8754088017203}, {"lng"=>-87.6364105939865, "lat"=>41.8754727110567}, {"lng"=>-87.6364642381668, "lat"=>41.8757642965932}, {"lng"=>-87.6371240615844, "lat"=>41.876678987795}, {"lng"=>-87.637939453125, "lat"=>41.8801059676767}, {"lng"=>-87.6379930973053, "lat"=>41.8806172030015}, {"lng"=>-87.6378536224365, "lat"=>41.8829017358812}, {"lng"=>-87.6375961303711, "lat"=>41.8844593251054}, {"lng"=>-87.6372849941253, "lat"=>41.8857213439117}, {"lng"=>-87.6371347904205, "lat"=>41.8860408383893}, {"lng"=>-87.6355576515197, "lat"=>41.8870552227663}, {"lng"=>-87.6282513141632, "lat"=>41.8870951588295}, {"lng"=>-87.6281654834747, "lat"=>41.8868076186168}]];
153:2439 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
Gmaps.map.create_polygons();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
```

Comment: Resulting js added to question...I should have thought of that.  Thanks!  I saw on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token that the problem was tab stops in the code.  I removed tab stops in my view and replaced with spaces, but no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I passed their base tutorial (from screen cast) and markers works fine. But I had problem with polylines (as you with polygons). At the end I resolved my problem (it can help you with polygons). 
So, view is the same as they gave :

```
<%= gmaps({
       "polylines"    => { "data" => @bemap_polylines }
     })
 %>
```

The model is also the same as their.

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bemap
  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
    #describe how to retrieve the address from your model, if you use directly a db column, you can dry your code, see wiki
    address
    logger.info address
  end

end
```

So, the main problem was into controller. Here is mine :

```
  def show
    @bemap = Bemap.find(params[:id])
    @bemap_polylines = []
    @bemap_characters = []
    @bemap.characters.each do |v|
      @bemap_characters << { :lng => v[:longitude], :lat => v[:latitude]}
    end
    @bemap_polylines << @bemap_characters
    @bemap_polylines =  @bemap_polylines.to_json
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bemap }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Gmaps4rails doesn't provide any builtin method to create the js for polygons.

The one you use is malformed, see doc: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Polygons.

Comment: I reformed the method to match the wiki (I think) and updated the question to reflect changes, but still getting the same error.  Do you see any obvious mistakes?  Thank you for the comment, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  It seems it has moved in the right direction, but displaying a new error.  Have you come across this before?Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latLngs' of undefined
Gmaps4Rails.a.adjustMapToBounds  application.js:19
Gmaps.load_map  153:2441
a.loadMaps  application.js:19
window.onload

Comment: Resulting js flags an error on this code: v = this.polygons;
                for (k = 0, o = v.length; k < o; k++) {
                    e = v[k], f = e.serviceObject.latLngs.getArray()[0].getArray();
                    for (l = 0, p = f.length; l < p; l++)
                        d = f[l], this.boundsObject.extend(d)
                }

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I'm in vacations now without any computer. Won't be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks apneadiving.  You were on the right track, apparently the system likes '@polyjson = [schoolpoints].to_json'.