# Gmaps4rails Polygon not displaying

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails, polygons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying a polygon with gmaps4rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618058/displaying-a-polygon-with-gmaps4rails)

Hi I am too a noob in gmap4rails and ruby. I have been successful in generating markers with my model but is unable to generate polygon with it. I was hoping **apneadiving** or anyone can help me with this. Appreciate any help please.

Controller (version 1) :

```
def index
  @polygon_points = PolygonPoint.all
  holder = PolygonPoint.all
  @json = holder.flatten.map{|h| {lng: h.longitude, lat: h.latitude}}.to_json

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @json }
  end
end
```

Controller (version 2 which i tried but didnt work as well) :

```
@json = PolygonPoint.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

Model:

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false
def gmaps4rails_address  
  "#{longitude}, #{latitude}"
end
```

View:

```
<%= gmaps({ "polygons" => {"data" => @json, "options" => { "fillColor" => "#000" }}})%>
```

I tried this view as well but it didn't work.

```
<%= gmaps("polygons" => { "data" => @json } )%>
```

Only by changing to "Markers", it worked fine but I want to display "polygons"

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => { "data" => @json } )%>
```