# Framey API - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" when I request json

Tags: javascript, json, format, response

I am using the Framey API for video recording. When I make a request I get back the json response I expect, but an error is raised:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Here's the javascript

```
var url = "http://framey.com/api/videos/ba9bd910-549d-012e-32f4-549a20bdfc52?
api_key=7VNKGLJZLKSASZ0FXN2TVSZQU&signature=41B08D68E0A4AC2DD91107BBD6AD08B8&time_stamp=1304447242";

$("button").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
          url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true

    }).done(function() { 
       $(".video").html("here it is babyF!");
     });
});
```

The url is just an example url from Framey's website, I don't know if it works. From reading this question [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), I think that I maybe having the same problem. The selected answer to that question is

> Just an FYI for people who might have the same problem -- I just had
>   to make my server send back the JSON as application/json and the
>   default jQuery handler worked fine.

I don't think I can effect the way Framey is sending me back the data, so I'm not sure how to fix this. Maybe it is something else all together? Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more information.

=========EDIT============

Here is the response from Framey that is giving me the error:

```
{"success":true,"video":{"name":"6d235a90-7b4b-012f-f97e-12313d297e67","filesize":1335504,"duration":20.48,"state":"uploaded","views":1,"data":{},"flv_url":"http://framey.com/videos/source/6d235a90-7b4b-012f-f97e-12313d297e67.flv","mp4_url":"http://framey.com/videos/source/6d235a90-7b4b-012f-f97e-12313d297e67.mp4","large_thumbnail_url":"http://framey.com/thumbnails/large/6d235a90-7b4b-012f-f97e-12313d297e67.jpg","medium_thumbnail_url":"http://framey.com/thumbnails/medium/6d235a90-7b4b-012f-f97e-12313d297e67.jpg","small_thumbnail_url":"http://framey.com/thumbnails/small/6d235a90-7b4b-012f-f97e-12313d297e67.jpg"}}
```

I think it is something about Framey putting "application/javascript" in the place where it should be saying "application/json"

============ EDIT 2 =================

Here are the headers for the response, I got these by looking at the "Network" section of the console in Chrome.

```
Request URL:http://www.framey.com/api/videos/32a7aaf0-7c3a-012f-37bd-12313b093125?api_key=00000000&signature=624643a3481b2a2c2bdb6c7cc29c506e&time_stamp=1536494436&callback=jQuery17202607689620926976_1336594235235&_=1336594483714
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=229279307.404664337.1336485291.1336573199.1336589854.6; __utmc=229279307; __utmz=229279307.1336485291.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _video-recorder_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlN2VjODBiYWM1NDk2MDlkYTg2ZTY0NzEzNDA5Zjg3ZGJJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjE4aW5KVktxakhyVTRvVGY0RXZlNkVkMU9lV0p1NUEzR01rVzlNK1hRWEJ3PQY7AEY%3D--b9a5f6cf08d7539d2bf9ebebc83ce96b0d070615
Host:www.framey.com
Referer:http://localhost:3000/questions/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
api_key:000000000000
signature:624643a3481b2a2c2bdb6c7cc29c506e
time_stamp:1536494436
callback:jQuery17202607689620926976_1336594235235
_:1336594483714
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:709
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
ETag:"5e8393861da01fa2effd911365a90e6b"
Server:nginx/1.0.10 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
Set-Cookie:_video-recorder_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlN2VjODBiYWM1NDk2MDlkYTg2ZTY0NzEzNDA5Zjg3ZGJJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjE4aW5KVktxakhyVTRvVGY0RXZlNkVkMU9lV0p1NUEzR01rVzlNK1hRWEJ3PQY7AEY%3D--b9a5f6cf08d7539d2bf9ebebc83ce96b0d070615; path=/; HttpOnly
Status:200
X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
X-Runtime:0.060476
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

Of particular interest is the content-type header: it is text/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you find that demo code (I could not find it on the Framey site)? I suspect you will run into cross-domain issues trying to use the Framey REST API from the client. Is your code on a publicly accessible server somewhere that we can take a look?

Comment: The code isn't a demo code, I just showed you the example URL from http://framey.com/docs/rest_api#auth. I don't want to show my developer key and secret so I just showed an example from Framey's site. I'm pretty sure there is nothing about cross domain problems because Framey is returning the correct json response. I can see it when I look at the error in the broswer console. I'll add that to my question.