# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ::

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, mime, getjson

In my application I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when using getJSON to fetch JSON from server.

This is the javascript I use:

```
$('#employeeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getEmployeeList();
});

setInterval ( "getEmployeeList()", 10000 );
var vanhadata = "";

function getEmployeeList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php?autonumero=' + autonumero + 'callback=?', function(data) {
       if(JSON.stringify(data) != JSON.stringify(vanhadata)){ 
            $('#employeeList li').remove();
            employees = data.key;
            $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
                $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="keikka.html?id=' + employee.IND + '">' +
                    '<h4>' + employee.OSO + '</h4>' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + employee.TILA + '.png"/>' +
                    '<p>' + employee.AIKA + '</p>' +'</a></li>');
        });
            $('#employeeList').listview('refresh');

            if(vanhadata != "")
               alert("Uusia keikkoja!");       
            vanhadata = data;
        }
    });
}
```

The JSON response from the server seems to be right but it shows error and no data is displayed. Console also prints: `"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:"`

This is the JSON response:

```
{
    "key": [
        {
            "NIMET": "Tuntematon",
            "PERHJAS": "0",
            "SAATTAJA": "0",
            "m_yht": "0",
            "OSO": null,
            "AIKA": "2010-03-11 10:00:00",
            "OSOITELAJI": "0",

        }
    ]
}UncaughtSyntaxError: Unexpectedtoken:
```

And the getemployees.php:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

include 'config.php'; 

$number = $_GET['autonumero'] ;

$sql = "select * from table where number=\"$number\"";



try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"key":'. json_encode($employees) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}


?>
```

When modify PHP file to:

```
           if ($_GET['callback'])
        print $_GET['callback']."(";

    echo '{"key":'. json_encode($results) .'}';  

  if ($_GET['callback'])
        print ")"; 

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

The response I get is:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CATCH in C:\Services\getemployees.php on line <i>40</i></th></tr>
</table></font>
```

So it is not JSON at all.

Comment: try running your JSON in a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/). Also, can you post the response text?

Comment: The JSON is not valid for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected token is not the `:`, it's the blank following the `:` in that message.

You need to remove the final comma in your inner object. Internet Explorer in particular objects to these trailing commas: it appears a comma means "There's something else to come," whereas other browsers use the comma to mean "That's the end of that one".

Because you're using `json_encode` that should be handled automatically, so you may be feeding it bad data. Check the data that's returned from your query: is there an empty row, perhaps?

Comment: A space between `<?php` and `header` won't do anything, the space would have to be before `<?php`.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any empty rows

Comment: @user1323294 Something is causing `json_encode` to put a blank line between the last comma and the `}`. That can only be data. My guess at the empty row was only a guess, because I don't know what the data is.

Answer (score 0):

Force your getemployees.php to print the content type of `application/json` instead of plain text

Comment: I have  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'); in the PHP file. That removes Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: part, but it still shows 
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: the problem is with your getemployees.php script, not the javascript. can you paste the code for that?

Comment: Hey dude look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412923/196917  seems like to be your type of issue. If it solves it, give him an upvote

Comment: I'm beginner with PHP so I don't really know how to modify my code to make it work like that. Could you provide me a sample code?

Comment: You see where he does checking for `if ($_GET['callback']) {
        print $_GET['callback']."(";
    }`

Comment: just add those two if statements around where you print the json string. ie. wrap your json string in that `jQuery17209314005577471107_1335958194322({JSONSTRING})` thingie

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11042/discussion-between-user1323294-and-reza-sanaie)