# JavaScript function, pass HTML as parameter

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, function, parameters

I have two functions in my script, one that outputs some long HTML string, the other one that takes this string as a parameter and processes it.

```
function myFirstFunction() {
    //output some HTML
    return myHTML;
}

var myHTML = myFirstFunction();

function mySecondFunction(myHTML) {
    //do something with parameter
}
```

For some reason that I can't figure out, the Chrome JS Console keeps giving me the following error:
**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"**

I thought maybe that was due to the fact, that the outputed HTML was pretty long since it seems to be working with small chunks of HTML.
Any thoughts? Thx!

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/utuGY/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @ sachleen "myHTML" is some long HTML output.
@ mcpDESIGNS yes it does work with short HTML strings.
@ Santiago Elvira Ramirez thanks, I'm looking at this answer right now, but it seems that the other person had her script working fine in Firefox, this is not my case.

Comment: @sf89 could show myHTML?

Answer (score 2):

Here's problem:

myHTML is a HTML **string** like this:

```
var myHTML ="<div id="foo"><div id='hello'>hello</div><div id="bar">bar'asdf'asf"sdf"&soidf;</div></div>";
```

That won't work because you have quotes and stuff inside it that are NOT escaped.

If you used `innerHTML` to get the HTML of an element on the page, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can escape them? I don't see how I can use innerHTML to serve that purpose... thanks for your help

Comment: @sf89 add slashes before the quotes to escape them from normal code; example: `var html = "<div class=\"container\"></div>";`

Answer (score 1):

myHTML is constructed with some < or > extra so verify the html string

Comment: I have, and really can't see extra "<"... Is there a tool that could double check for me?

Comment: open one new html file and copy there the html then you check it

Comment: thanks! I tried it, but it seems my html is clean so the error doesn't might not come from it

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to pass an html text as a parameter to javascript function: Just replace all specifics chars in html tag before you pass it to javascript function. Later in javascript you just revert all specific chars back to normal. The trick is to cause javascript recognizes only those chars it excepted.

Example:

[[C#]]

```
string urlString = "http://localhost:8698/DotNetNuke_Community_06.02.01_Install/Default.aspx?TabID=157&categoryId=92&newCategoryId=92";

                urlString = urlString.Replace("<", "µ");
                urlString = urlString.Replace(">", "Ħ");
                urlString = urlString.Replace("&", "€");
                urlString = urlString.Replace(":", "¥");
                urlString = urlString.Replace("=", "¬");
                urlString = urlString.Replace("/", "ä");
                urlString = urlString.Replace("?", "¿");
                urlString = urlString.Replace("'", "ʅ");
function(urlString);
```

[[Javascript]]

```
function(urlString){
urlString = urlString.replace(/µ/g, "<");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/Ħ/g, ">");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/€/g, "&");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/¥/g, ":");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/¬/g, "=");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/ä/g, "/");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/¿/g, "?");
        urlString = urlString.replace(/ʅ/g, "'");
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you're literally trying to pass html, not in a string literal.  If you try something like:

```
myFunction(<html><body>...);
```

That'll definitely through an error. You need to use string literals:

```
myFunction("<html><body>...");
```

If you're using html that has quotes in it, you need to escape them or use single quotes:

```
"<div id="name">"
```

is not a valid string.  Make it either:

```
"<div id=\"name\">" or
'<div id="name">'
```

Comment: This is an ajax context. So I have:
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>

var string = "<?php echo $myHTML ?>";
receiveMessage(string);
As you can see, I am putting quotes as I think they should be. Or is it wrong?

Comment: I don't know what the contents of $myHTML, so I have literally no idea what needs to be escaped.  Can you just post what the contents of $myHTML are as it exists on the PHP side?  You may need to [escape it on the php side](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Output of the function on the php side:
echo '<div class="box_img">
   <img src="myLogo.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="new_box">
   <div class="triangle_left_2"></div>
   <div class="triangle_left_1"></div>
   <div class="username">USER</div>
   <div class="rt-button">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-lang="en" data-text="'.$a_first_var.'">ReTweet</a>
   </div>
   <div class="txt_item"><p>'.utf8_decode($some_var).'</p></div>
  </div>';

Comment: Try wrapping that call to utf8_decode() in htmlspecialchars()

Comment: I just tried that, but it's throwing me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & "