# Unexpected < error from a get variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting an error that says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

After simplying the problem a lot, it's come down to one line that does not make any sense to me.  Basically, whenever we get keyup on the input field for the promo code, we check if it's a valid promo code.  Now I've simplified it down to this level.  First, here is the jquery

```
$('#promo_code_field').bind('keyup', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "functions/ajaxProcessPromoCode.php",
        data: "original_price=2.99" + "&series_number=0" + "&promo_code=test20",
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see the data is hardcoded in this case, and the success response is blank so there's nothing there to cause the error.  The php file it calls is as such

```
<?php
    $original_price = $_GET['original_price'];
    $promo_code = $_GET['promo_code'];
    $series_number = $_GET['series_number'];

    $return_data = array("price" => 2.99, "display_text" => "", "series_number" => 0);
    echo json_encode($return_data);
?>
```

As you can see this is all hardcoded now as well, and for simplicity's sake there's no validation of GET variables or any other checks - everything is down to the absolute minimum.  Running this results in the "Unexpected token <" error.  In order to fix this error, all I have to do is remove the $series_number assignment.  What I cannot get is how this assignment could possibly cause the error.  It makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: The thing is, in JavaScript, an error appearing at location x in your code can actually be caused due to an error at location x-1 (earlier) in your code, it's as if you'd crash into a building -- the building is damaged and some how you do not see what's wrong with the wall; look outside and take a look at the car that just crashed :) (Consider adding more code)

Comment: But why would removing that one variable assignment on the php side remove all the errors from showing up?  It's a 1-to-1 error per keyup until I remove that single php variable assignment, at which point all errors are gone.

Edit - the full version was fleshed out with full functionality, but even there removing that one variable assignment fixed all the errors.  Of course it meant I couldn't track series numbers anymore.

Comment: @Jonast92: isn't it a little bit too abstract and philosophic? :)

Comment: What content does the service actually return.  It might be just dumping back the whole php file, hence the unexpected < character.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token#answer-20672598

Comment: It's returning the new price after applying the promo code, the status text to show along with it, and also the series number so I know how recent it was (since some times things get sent back out of order if you type quickly on a laggy connection).  It's not dumping back the whole php file because it does work 100% correctly (this is will all the implementation put back in, which is longish).  The exception is that if I use the series_number GET variable, then it returns nothing at all.  I'll look into that link.

Comment: Well I'm testing the JSON at http://jsonlint.com/ and it is saying that is valid JSON.

Comment: Strange.  You should try using your browsers developer tools.  Server must be sending back < somewhere.  I would also send back a header("Content-type: application/json"); in the php file.

Comment: Oh well adding that header removed the error.  Let me see real quick if the functionality is working as intended now like it was before I added the series_number.

Comment: Yep it all works now.  Thanks Phil!

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add:

```
console.log(response)
```

and look in the developer tools to see the format of the JSON object being returned.

This may be your issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672598/3313754