# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" while using $.load jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `$("#selector").load("url")` to load partial view into my `selector` element like one below:

```
$("#body_data").load("/Admin/GetUploadVideos", initializeVideoDetails);
```

and AdminController `ActionMethod` will be

```
public ActionResult GetUploadVideos()
{
    return PartialView("_UploadVideos");
}
```

But I am getting **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"** in console. No issues in loading `partialview` but this console error is bit irritating.

I am not sure why this is happening. I went through different links like **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)** but no where this problem wasn't mentioned for `$("#selector").load` event. Is there any format that has to be specified while loading the `partialviews` using `.load` or the only way left to load the `partialviews` now is using `$.ajax`? Any information appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Tried @ShaunakD's suggestion, getting successful response but view is not getting appended to `selector` and the `console` error still exists

```
$.ajax({
          url:'/Admin/GetUploadVideos',
          dataType:'html',
          type:'GET',
          success:function(result){
                 $("#body_data").append($.parseJSON(result));
                 initializeVideoDetails()
          },
          error:function(result){
                 toastr.error("Error Loading View","Error");
          }
})
```

when `console.log(result)` is done on `success` I am getting html of PartialView in `console` but it will not get appended to `selector`

Comment: @Tushar `html` instead of `partialviews`? How can I do that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: returning `PartialView` is correct approach

Comment: @Tushar. Will that apply to `MVC`?

Comment: Yea @Satpal but how to overcome this console error? Any idea on that?

Comment: This should ideally work. Try out `$.ajax` way with `dataType` as `'html'` [Reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, JavaScript is abstract from MVC. You can use JavaScript in any web technology.

Comment: @ShaunakD. Sure. I'll give that a try! Will there be any downside for this if I use `$.ajax` instead of `$.load` to load `partialviews`?

Comment: Not sure about the downside, as load is almost equivalent to ajax.

Comment: @ShaunakD.. Alright. let me try.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, There must be error in `_UploadVideos` partial view

Comment: @Satpal.. The case is same for all the `PartialViews` and there is no problem either in rendering or any other breakdown..