# How can I access the JSON data through jQuery ajax calling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to access the url and will get the JSON response, but I can't able to access the JSON data, it **show Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

I try the following code

```js
$(window).load(function () {
        retrivefun();

    });

    function retrivefun() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.railwayapi.com/live/train/56700/doj/20150908/apikey/mdqjs5581"',
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Not Loaded");
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successfully Loaded");
                debugger;
                console.log(data)
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: just access it on success like `console.log(data)`

Comment: There is an additional `"` (double quote) in your `url` string at the end. Remove it and it will work fine.

Comment: Looks like jsonp support or CORS is not there for the said resource... so you may not be able to request the API from the browser.... you might have to use your web server to sent the request to the server

Comment: There is some **`parsererror`** in the response you are receiving...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao This is the common website for viewing train enquiry, also many one use this. So I am surly the server side no problem.

Comment: because when I debugged it and checked using `error:function(request, status, error)` I just logged the status and request to check actually what was happening and it was pointing to the very first line of the `API` which was `error`.

Comment: I think, I can able to access from server side code only.

Comment: @MerbinJoe yes you are right... from your script sent a request to your server which can make the http call to the api and return the result back to the script

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please give, previously you posted answer again. you deleted it

Comment: @MerbinJoe that is not a solution to the problem... I misread the error....

Comment: @ArunPJohny I need it for my another problem. give me the link through jsfiddle

Comment: @MerbinJoe https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvh6bzqL/1/ - it always will log error because of `Same Origin Policy` violation

Comment: Did you guys notice my answer?
I think his API is giving back an `Authentication error`

Comment: @KasunRandika did you see the extra `"` at the end of the url... remove it and check.. probably a copy paste mistake from the OP

Comment: I just noticed it @ArunPJohny sure, I will check it too.

Comment: Here is another question similar to this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: Guys, I removed the Additional `"`  which is at the end of the URL.
Now it fetches me the response too in the network tab, nor more Authorization errors. But it seems like that YOUR RESPONSE JSON is not correctly formatted. I will update my answer with the RESPONSE JSON and Network tab.

Comment: I update the answer. I think OP should check it!Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the bellow code snippet. I update your AJAX call's error handling part.

```js
$(window).load(function () {
        retrivefun();

    });

    function retrivefun() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.railwayapi.com/live/train/56700/doj/20150908/apikey/mdqjs5581',
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("response : "+xhr.responseText+"\n status: "+status+"\n error: "+error);
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successfully Loaded");
                debugger;
                console.log(data)
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And whenever you run it try to pop up the Console and Network tabs of FireFox or Chrome browsers. It seems to be like your API call is not authorized correctly plus that error message sent from the server is not correct JSON, so AJAX call is giving a `parsererror` as the status (Refer to the screenshots for this).

**FireFox web dev console tab:**
[image]

**FireFox web dev Network Tab:**
[image]

**Update:**
Before the URL was as follows
`url: 'http://api.railwayapi.com/live/train/56700/doj/20150908/apikey/mdqjs5581`

So that's what gave that

> Authentication Error

Anyway now it fetches the response as follows if you could view it in the network tab of your browser:
[image]

But still console tab of the browser shows the following:
[image]

Which it still says it is not able to process the response. May be that's an error made from the server itself.

**Hint:** Check the generated RESPONSE with a JSON Validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Hope this answer was helpful to the OP to anyone else!
Cheers!