# VM1290 app.html:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting this error in my code...

VM1290 app.html:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

I have searched a ton, but I can't seem to find how to resolve the error. At first I thought it was an illegal invisible character, so I retyped all my code. Then I ran my code, but I still got the error! Please help. Here is my code

```
function battle(src) {
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = 'none';
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    document.getElementById("attack-content").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("creature_attacker").src = src;
    //The if statment choosing what the computer will choose for a creature
    if (random === 1) {
        document.getElementById("computer_attackercom").src = 'resources/creatures/pug.png';
    } else if (random === 2) {
        document.getElementById("computer_attackercom").src = 'resources/creatures/goat.png';
    } else if (random === 3) {
        document.getElementById("computer_attackercom").src = 'resources/creatures/brid.png';
    } else if (random === 4) {
        document.getElementById("computer_attackercom").src = 'resources/creatures/deer.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("computer_attackercom").src = 'resources/creatures/moose.png';
    }
    let attackedTrue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (attackedTrue >= 5) {
            alert("You Lost! -50 Cash! -5 Pods!");
            user_Cash_amount += 50;
            num0_pods205 += 5;
            document.getElementById("attack-content").style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            alert("You Win! +100 Cash! +5 Pods!");
            user_Cash_amount += 100;
            num0_pods205 += 5;
            document.getElementById("attack-content").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, 2000);
};
```

Comment: `user_Cash_amount` is not initialised anywhere

Comment: I'm hoping you did initialize their values somewhere or obtaining them from other part of the code.

Comment: I am not getting the error - https://jsfiddle.net/dhk3aezw/

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I have the variables stored in another file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token Did you try to refer to this?

Comment: I don't think the problem is arising here, it might be with some other part of your code.

Comment: Yes, It might be... I have another file - Main.js with variables and other functions. One function calls on this function..