# Deploy django with react on heroku, Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have a simple django with react project and I want to publish it on heroku.
I use webpack-bundle-tracker to get django and react working together.
If I run it on my computer (first webpack, then runserver), everything works, but deployed on heroku, I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and if I open the bundle.js in chromes dev-tools, which is generated by the bundle-tracker and webpack, I see the same as in the index.html.

I installed whitenoise helping with staticfiles, but this doesnt help.

Here are the important files (lines):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>The App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/dist/styles.css" />        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        {% render_bundle 'main' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**settings.py** (just the important lines)

```
import django_heroku
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['static'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/dist/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**package.json** (just the scripts)

```
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build:prod"
  },
```

**Procfile** (needed for heroku deployment)

```
web: gunicorn backend.wsgi
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production';
    const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

    return {
        entry: './assets/js/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: CSSExtract.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }, {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }]
        },
        plugins: [
            CSSExtract,
            new BundleTracker({ filename: './webpack-stats.json' }),
            //makes jQuery available in every module
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            })
        ],
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
            historyApiFallback: true,
            publicPath: '/bundles/'
        }
    };
};
```

And finally the error i get: 
[I dont know if you can see it, the h1 is there, to see if index.html is even loaded properly and potentially showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOUNq.png)

As mentioned before, it seems like the bundle.js has the same lines of code as the index.html (except the django specific lines which were replaced). Therefore the error itself, is clear I think, its a .js (jsx) file and theres the `<` at the beginning. But why it doesnt get compiled like on my local machine, I don't know.

I tried uploading the compiled files in the repository before, but the error was the same (in this instance I removed the heroku-postbuild script, so that the precompiled files were not overwritten).

**Any** kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution, and indeed, it wasn't the code. Solution was to add an additional Buildpack under the settings on heroku. Add 'heroku/nodejs' before 'heroku/python' to compile the frontend first, which then can be used.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem with the code you've posted, but that somehow your /static/ URLs are being served by your index view. You might need to show your wsgi and urls files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: Hmm ok, could you help with that.
This is the urls.py: 
`from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from api import urls as api_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urls)),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r'^(?:.*)/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),  
]
`
The api-app is the backend, `r'^(?:.*)/?$'` this url is for the routing through react-router, which is the nhandled in an extra Router.

Comment: Additionaly, what I think is strange, is that it works locally, and just on heroku theres the error.