# Syntax error in openweathermap API request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp, openweathermap, angularjs-factory

I'm getting the following syntax error in the console while trying to get data from 'openweathermap'

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Here is the JS file :

```js
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('weatherService', function($http) {
  return {
    getWeather: function() {
      var weather = '';
      //  if (!!prmSearchValue) {
      //   var searchValue = prmSearchValue;
      $http.jsonp('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=c19bc0731cec50456576c7b36a675ca7&mode=json').success(function(data) {
        weather = 3232;
      });
      //  }
      /*   else {
          weather = {};
        } */
      return weather;
    }
  };
});
//Eilat,Israel
app.controller('httpAppCtrlr', function($scope, weatherService) {
  $scope.searchText = '';
  $scope.searchWeather = function() {
    var prmSearchValue = $scope.searchText;
    $scope.weather = weatherService.getWeather();
  };
});
```

[image: Console]

It looks as if the data that returns is broken in some way..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/4hagbjny/)

Comment: I tried using a JSON formatter and it says the JSON retrieved is valid but the dev console is giving me the same error it's giving you :( Check [this link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AngularJS` `jsonp`, you need to append `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to the url.  (I'll assume there is a reason you're using `jsonp` instead of `get`.)

Replace

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=c19bc0731cec50456576c7b36a675ca7&mode=json
```

with

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=c19bc0731cec50456576c7b36a675ca7&mode=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s0Lnpxz/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Use **`$http Get`** instead of JSONP. Better way to handle the error is using **`.then`**, Change your Factory as follows,

```
app.factory('weatherService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getWeather: function () {
            var weatherForcast = {};
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=c19bc0731cec50456576c7b36a675ca7"

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                angular.extend(weatherForcast, response.data);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert('API call failed, possibly due to rate limiting or bad zip code.');
            });
            return weatherForcast;
        }
    };
});
```

**[`WORKING FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/fpw3jukz/)**

Comment: Maybe OP wants to use `jsonp`.  This simply replaces `jsonp` with `get`.