# Why do I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in browser each time after "npm run build"?

Tags: reactjs, https, service-worker

I got my project using React service worker deployed to https server, every thing works fine except that each time when I do "npm run build", I got this error in browser and browser stays blank. I have to refresh the browser the second time, then everything works normal again. This happens on Windows chrome or iOS Safari, and also on home screen shortcut on iPhone. I have been struggling with this for days and read and tried a lot of related suggestions, but nothing works for me. What's the fix?

Comment: are you using an .htaccess file? Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: No, I'm not using .htaccess file. I'm using express server.