# Inserting html in ckeditor causes syntaxerror ( laravel )

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-blade

I'm trying out the CKeditor in laravel and I encountered an issue inserting html into the editor. After appending the editor I'd like to set the value so you can edit the already existing values.

HTML:

```
@if (!empty($proposal->reference_sites))
    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
        <label for="reference_sites" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-lg">Reference sites:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" id="reference_sites"></div>
    </div>
@endif
```

JS:

```
if($('#reference_sites').length){
    $output = "<textarea id='ckeditor-rs' name='ckeditor-rs' rows='10' cols='80'></textarea>";
    $('#reference_sites').append($output);
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor-rs');

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor-rs'];
    editor.setData("{!!html_entity_decode($proposal->reference_sites)!!}");

    }else{
        console.log("couldn't append ckeditor in rs");
    }
```

As you see I'm trying to decode the HTML and set that as the HTML of the CKeditor.

`$proposal->reference_sites` contains this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>site one</li>
    <li>site two</li>
    <li>site 3</li>
</ul>
```

Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token <`

I'm not entirely sure what causes this error since when I only decode a variable which contains `<p>some text</p>` it inserts `some text` into the editor.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to do it without html_entity_decode

Comment: returns the same error but instead of html i get `&lt;ul&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;site one&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;site two&lt;/li&gt;
 &lt;li&gt;site 3&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;`

Comment: editor.setData("{$proposal->reference_sites}");

Comment: Alright after 3 hours I finally found out what the problem was. In the database you have the "enter" entities too and they messed up the javascript as it would litterally put an enter in there.

Answer (score 1):

try the following one,

```
if($('#reference_sites').length){
$output = "<textarea id='ckeditor-rs' name='ckeditor-rs' rows='10' cols='80'></textarea>";
$('#reference_sites').append($output);
CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor-rs');

var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor-rs'];
editor.setData("{{$proposal->reference_sites}}");

}else{
    console.log("couldn't append ckeditor in rs");
}
```

Comment: this inserts `{$proposal->reference_sites}` as html. Which is the variable name and not the value of the variable.

Comment: i assume $proposal->reference_sites contains html,you can try to echo as html string 
editor.setData("<?php echo $proposal->reference_sites ?>");
if its not,then you are make some syntax error

Comment: Like I said in the original question the error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token < line 254

Comment: check this ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191090/discussion-between-error70-and-sylent).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one code:

```
if($('#reference_sites').length){
    $output = "<textarea id='ckeditor-rs' name='ckeditor-rs' rows='10' cols='80'></textarea>";
    $('#reference_sites').append($output);
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor-rs');

    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() { 
            CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement() 
        });
    }
}else{
    console.log("couldn't append ckeditor in rs");
}
```